unmittelbar bevorstehen
I read the following sentence in https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/israel-gallant-abloesung-100.html:

Steht Gallants Rauswurf unmittelbar bevor?

Given that "bevorstehen" means "to be imminent" and "unmittelbar" means "immediate", isn't "unmittelbar" redundant in this sentence? DeepL translates the sentence without it:
Is Gallant's sacking imminent?

"To be imminent" has a connotation of time pressure that "bevorstehen" lacks. In fact "bevorstehen" just means that something is due and the "within some relatively near future" is just a connotation. e.g.:

Eine neue Eiszeit steht bevor.

doesn't meant that a new ice age begins within the next days, weeks or months. It might take thousands of years, but it will come eventually.
To add that meaning of "imminence" or "immediaticity" (yes, I know this word is made up) the "unmittelbar" is added. Something is not only due eventually but within a very very short timeframe.
